# find the five different ways to combine 100 pennies, quarters, and dimes to get $\$4.99$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

here's where I am so far.

I define two equations with three variables

- $q$: the number of quarters,
- $p$: the number of pennies, and
- $d$: the number of  dimes.

\begin{gather*}
p+d+q = 100\\\\
25q+10d+p = 499
\end{gather*}

I eliminate $q$ by substitution and get
$$
24p+15d = 2001
$$

now I'm lost.  I think this has something to do with the $\gcd(24,15) = 3$.

however, I am unsure how to apply this information.   I am certainly more interested in the process than just the solution.   I'm having some trouble with how to solve a two variable equation.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euclidean algorithm? You can use it not only to find gcd but also the coefficients of 24p + 15d = 2001

Comment: I am familiar with it, but not entirely sure how to apply it here. the examples I have give the format $ax+by=$ gcd($a,b$).    how do I apply this to any value $c$ such that $c=ax+by$?

Comment: There is a slip in the elimination. Will write a solution.

Comment: I don't think you mean coefficients, @Sid.

Comment: Why not divide both sides of $24p+15d=2001$ by $3$?

Comment: Remember, you also need $p+d\leq 100$, or else $q<0$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elimination is a good idea.  I think the details are not done correctly. In any case, I would rather eliminate $p$, the arithmetic is easier. We get
$24q+9d=399$, or equivalently
$$8q+3d=133.$$

We can use general techniques to solve this Diophantine equation, but the numbers are so small that it does not seem worthwhile.  Note that when $q=2$, then $133-8q$ is a multiple of $3$, and we get $q=2$, $d=39$, and therefore $p=59$.

Now we have found one solution. We need others.

Go back to the equation $8q+3d=133$. We have found one solution, $q=2$, $d=39$. 
For any integer $k$, we therefore have
$$8(2+3k)+3(39-8k)=133.$$
(Note the cancellation.)

Substitute various values of $k$. With $k=1$, for example, we get the solution $q=5$, $d=31$. That gives $p=64$.

Continue, using $k=2$, $3$, and so on. For the sake of reality, we will have to make sure that our values of $q$, $d$, $p$ are all $\ge 0$. We cannot use $k\gt 4$, for that would give negative $d$.

Comment: your original solution results in $d$ = 39, but you input 59 into the equations with $k$. additionally, are there resources where I could learn to solve this more generally?  most of my homework is more complex than this problem.   I picked this one so I could see the concepts at work

Comment: Thank you, "typos," fixed. Any basic number theory book has the material. Given a linear Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$, if $\gcd(a,b)$ does not divide $c$, there is no solution, and if it does divide, there is a solution. Divide through by $\gcd(a,b)$. So we may assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to begin with.  Now find one **particular** solution $(x_0,y_0)$. For small numbers, this is done by inspection. For big numbers, use the **Extended Euclidean Algorithm** to solve $as+bt=1$, and multiply $s$, $t$ by $c$. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) There is a general theorem that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ is a particular solution, then **all* solutions are given by $x=x_0+kb$, $y=y_0-ka$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single "best" way to solve a problem like this, but here's an approach that works well.

Eliminate the *dimes* from $p+d+q=100$ and $p+10d+25q=499$ to get

$$9p-15q=501$$

Dividing both sides by $3$ and moving things around gives

$$5q=3p-167$$

Clearly we need to choose $p$ so that the right hand side is a *non-negative* multiple of $5$.  A little trial and error produces $p=59$ as the smallest such number, with $q=2$ as the corresponding number of quarters (and thus $d=39$ for the number of dimes).  You get more solutions by incrementing $p$ by multiples of $5$, i.e.,

$$p=59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84,\ldots$$
with corresponding $q$s in increments of $3$:
$$q=2,5,8,11,14,17,\ldots$$
This gives the total number(s) of pennies plus dimes as
$$p+q=61,69,77,85,93,101,\ldots$$
and from this we see why there are only five solutions:  You can't have $p+q=101$, since that would require a "negative" dime.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the equation to $8p+5d = 667$. Solve $8p_0+5d_0=1$ for integers $p_0,d_0$. Let $p_1=667p_0$ and $d_1=667d_0$. Then $p_1,d_1$ are integer solutions to $8p+5d=667$, and you can write any solution to this as:

$$p=p_1+5k, d=d_1-8k$$
for some integer $k$.[*]

Now you need to add the conditions:

$$p\geq 0, d\geq 0, p+d\leq 100$$ to get all valid values of $k$.

[*] More generally, if $a,b$ are relatively prime and $x_0,y_0,c$ are integers so that  $ax_0+by_0=c$ then the complete set of integer solutions to $ax+by=c$ are the pairs $(x,y)=(x_0+bk,y_0-ak)$. where $k$ can be any integer.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using generating formula. Restriction of 100 coins will make things even more complicated. You idea of substitution is OK. I use Andre  Nicholas substittuition, because it's more easier to work with it.

The generating formula for the first term is:

$$(1 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{24}...)$$

The generating formula for the second term is:

$$(1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9...)$$

Now we multiply and we want to find the coefficient in front of $x^{133}$

We can simplyfy the generating formulas for the terms in:

$$(1 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{24}...) = \frac{1}{1-x^8} \quad (1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9...) = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^8} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^3} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)}$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)} = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2 (1+x) (1+x^2) (1+x+x^2) (1+x^4)} = M$$

After doing partial fraction composition we have:

$$M = \frac{1-x}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} + \frac{x^3-x^2+x+1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{x^4+1} + \frac{3}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Now we work on this fractions to get the coefficient in front of $x^{133}$

$$\frac{1}{8}\frac{1-x}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{8}(1-x)(1-x^2+x^4-x^6...+x^{132}+...)$$

So we have one possibility for $x^{133}$, which is wehn we multiply $x^{132}$ and $-x$. So the coefficient will be $-\frac{1}{8}$

$$\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x^2+x+1} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1-x}{1-x^3} = \frac{1}{3}(1-x)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9...+x^{132}+...)$$

In this case the coefficient will be $-\frac{1}{3}$

$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{x^3-x^2+x+1}{1+x^4} = \frac 14 (x^3-x^2+x+1)(1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+...-x^{132})$$

In this case the coefficient will be $-\frac{1}{4}$

$$\frac{3}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{3}{16}(1+x+x^2+x^3...)$$

So the coefficient will be $\frac{3}{16}$

$$\frac{1}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{16}(1-x+x^2-x^3...-x^{133})$$

So the coefficient will be $-\frac{1}{16}$

$$\frac{1}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{24}(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...+134x^{133})$$

So the coefficiet will be $\frac{134}{24}$

Now since we exhausted all the cases we add the coefficients:

$$- \frac 18 - \frac 13 - \frac 14 + \frac{3}{16} - \frac {1}{16} + \frac{134}{24} = 5$$

So there are five solutions to: $8q + 3d = 133$

And indeed solutions are ordered triples $(q,d,p) = (2,39,59), (5,31,64), (8,23,69), (11,15,74), (14,7,79)$